Can't remove file from git that starts with backspace "\b"
I have a very strange situation where I received a private repo from a past developer. One of the folders in the repo starts with a hidden character, specifically the backspace char, or '\b'. My attempt to rename/remove the folder from git causes the following error on MacOS:
fatal: pathspec 'dir1/dir2/dir3/\btarget/file.rb' did not match any files
I changed the folder names to protect the innocent, but you get the idea.
Interesting, on Windows it won't even let me checkout this repo as windows won't allow for such a messed up file name. Any thoughts on how to get around this would be greatly appreciated. Btw, the repo is hosted on a private BitBucket repo. I took a quick look and I couldn't find a way to make the change there so doing this on a Mac might be my only option. That or just creating a whole new repo and move forward from there.

cant you just tab complete the name to pass as the git command parameter?

@Randommm That would solve the issue from the shell, but the git app itself can't deal with it. I ended up just creating a new repo for this, which is fine but frustrating.  I suspect the weird file name was created when they converted from some other repo system like SVN or whatever, no idea, but I can't see how this ever came about normally.
